# Noob C++/OpenMP: Why do I get this compile time error? variable in 'reduction' clause must be shared in enclosing context

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp, reduction

```
 1 int result = 0;
 2 int b = 0;
 3 #pragma  omp for reduction(+:result) private(b)
 4 for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
 5    ifile >> b;
 6    if(b== 100)
 7      result++;
 8 }
```

**Why do I get this error?**

(3) error C3037: 'result' : variable in 'reduction' clause must be shared in enclosing context

I tried googling btw... all the examples look like this. I am also coding this in visual studios 2012 if that matters. I hate asking a question like this, but it is blocking me from continuing.

**Fixed: add parallel**

`#pragma  omp parallel for private(buffer) reduction(+:result)`

Comment: Why downvote? I do not see anything wrong with the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the "parallel" tag from the reduction clause:

```
#pragma  omp for reduction(+:result) private(b)
```

should be

```
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:result) private(b)
```

Comment: Thanks. What you said didn't fix it however you gave me an idea and it works now. I needed to add the keyword "parallel"

Comment: @LLL: Updated my answer to reflect your actual problem ;)